# Direct way to get element that event bubbled up to, within .on() function handler

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery's `.on()`:

```
$('.outer').on('click', '.inner', function(){
    // doing stuff...
});
```

Since `this` refers to the origniting (`.inner`) element, is there a more direct reference to the parent element that the event bubbled up to, than by using:

```
$(this).closest('.outer')
```

?

Comment: are you looking for `.parent()`?

Comment: you could use .parents() - here is a link to a test case showing performance between the two: http://jsperf.com/jquery-parents-vs-closest/2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use **[`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/)** where `event` is the argument to the handler.

```
$('.outer').on('click', '.inner', function(e) {
    // e.delegateTarget === The '.outer' on which .on() was bound
});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.outer').on('click', '.inner', function(e){
    console.log(e.delegateTarget);
    //to get jq object, wrap it: $(e.delegateTarget)
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/37yLM/